# Installing kali on usb with early 2015 macbook pro

Tags: linux, kali-linux

I've tried a fee different ways to install but none work.

1. I used the mac linux usb loader but I got an error "(unable to find a medium containing a libe file system).
2. I also used the unmount dd approach but holding down option key doesn't show the usb.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the iso.
2. Open Terminal
3. Convert the iso to dmg (I don't know if this is actually necessary ...)
   Code:

hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/kali.img ~/path/to/kali.iso

4. Plug in USB key
5. In terminal type
   Code:

df

and note the location of the usb key. It will probably be something like
Code:

/dev/disk1s1

or
Code:

/dev/disk2s1

. You can also use
Code:

diskutil list

to get the same info.

In my case the USB was found at
Code:

/dev/disk1s1

.

What you need going in following steps is the portion /dev/diskN where N is the disk number you found before. In my case it was
Code:

/dev/disk1

6. Now unmount the USB key using either Disk Utilities or from the Terminal
   Code:

diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk1

7. In the terminal type
   Code:

sudo dd if=kali.dmg of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=512k

.... Supposedly using /dev/rdiskN is faster.

You will get a Finder message that it can't mount the drive. This is likely because OSX can't read ext3/4.

8. Unmount the USB key
   Code:

diskutil eject /dev/disk1

where N is your USB

9. Reboot and press "Alt/Option" key to select kali. 
   from [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?303-Kali-Linux-install-to-USB-key-using-Mac)

Comment: Does not work. When I restart the computer, I only see the mac disk. The other disk does not show. I think the key is that this is a macbook pro early 2015. Any other suggestions?